# The Blazor WebAssembly project 's hot reload not working in the VS Code remote SSH

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

The Blazor WebAssembly is working on my local PC, But when I remote the PC by the vscode remote ssh. The Hot reload is not working.
The specific reason is the hot reload needs two extra ports to communicate with the (dotnet watch run) by the web socket.

[image]

These two ports are not auto-forwarding by the Vs Code. Also, the ports are random.

So when we start `dotnet watch run` , it can not launch the Browser on my PC, and it prompts with the message 'dotnet watch connecting the browser is taking longer than expected...'
[image]

I can not search for some resolutions about it. I have no way to determine whether this is my problem or not.

Help, please.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/31735 this is a issue about fixed blazor wss ports